# Angular 5 : Deploy app to IIS under nested folder

Tags: angular, iis, url-rewriting, angular5, angular-routing

I am using **Angular 5.2** and deployed in my **localhost IIS server** and it is working fine.

my localhost URL looks like this :- http://localhost/DEV

DEV is the virtual directory in my localhost IIS server. Everything is working fine with the above URL.

Now i want to add another nested VD inside the DEV as childApp.
I want my app to work as **http://localhost/DEV/childApp**.

So I changed the index.html content to have the base href like this :-

```
<base href="/DEV/childApp/">
```

And also updated the web.config file for the URL rewrite rule to be:-

From

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
```

TO

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="/DEV/childApp/" />
```

Web.config looks like this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
           <action type="Rewrite" url="/DEV/childApp/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But it is throwing me the error saying :-

**HTTP Error 500.52 - URL Rewrite Module Error. Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'rule' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'Angular Routes'**

Please suggest how to fix the web.config for URL rewriting or other place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL Rewrite error with Web Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250842/url-rewrite-error-with-web-applications)

Comment: This is different and has to do with Angular application & its base href.

Comment: Not if that is the error that you are getting. That is not an Angular error but rather an IIS error. Did you add the `<clear />` as the answer gave?

Comment: Thanks Daniel W Strimpel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `<clear />` to the web.config is the solution.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
       <clear /> <!--Imperative Step, otherwise IIS will throw err-->
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          ............
          ..........
```